# CSS Inline into External CSS File (Not working)

Tags: html, css

I have tried to call CSS many ways but it just didn't work.

First of all, CSS inline something like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 30px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
text-align: left; line-height: 60px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 50px;
color: #FFFFFF;">
    HELLO
</div>
```

Secondly, I move the style into external file something like this (HTML file):

```
<div class="slideHeader">
    HELLO
</div>
```

in CSS would be like this:

```
.slideHeader {position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 30px; left: 30px;
padding: 5px;text-align: left; line-height: 60px; text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 50px; color: #FFFFFF;}
```

External file I put something like this in HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/css/style.css">
```

Notes: I have tried to view page source to call CSS, I checked and it's linking very well. But it just didn't work at all on my webpage. It should be working with this. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `color` is `#FFF`...which is white. Change that to `#000` (black) and it shows up just fine.

Comment: can you recreate this somehow, or post a link to your site or something? How is anyone supposed to help with this?

Comment: yeah you post some code and we are not magican..

Comment: Please tell me your background isn't 'background: #ffffff'... See here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbgOQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you call a stylesheet:

```
<script type="stylesheet" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/css/style.css"</script>
```

`<script></script>` is reserved for javascript not css and it wasn't closed right anyways. it should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. Lol, very weird question thou. Too careless :/ @jmore009

Answer (score 0):

The link to external CSS was wrong.

```
<link type="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/css/style.css">
```

The real one is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/assets/css/style.css">
```

I have made this work. Thanks guys!